# Cakephp 2.1 White Screen on Devserver

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

We created a subdomain on our server. First we tested that HTML worked, then I did phpinfo() and everything worked fine there. But when I moved the entire Cakephp app to the devserver at:

```
dev.lessonshark.com
```

I get a white screen. But I can go to:

```
dev.lessonshark.com/css/front.css
```

and that routes fine.

What I have done so far:

```
1. Made debug in core set to 3.
2. Removed all the cache files in tmp folder.
```

Still no luck, any ideas?

Comment: Debug mode should not be 3, try with making it 2.

Comment: you have to start from index.php,
check it line by line,
it could be wrong configuration in your .htaccess something terrible in php code or something wrong in php.ini

Comment: @jain: debug 1, 2, 3, and 0 all give white screen; @ sukinsan, checking line by line in index.php now

Comment: It's about debugging step by step without code review its bit difficult to find out the problem.

Comment: Going through the apache/php logs may give the answer but a quick and ditry way would be to set display_errors to "on" in the php.ini and then you should see the specifics of the error. Probably best to HTTP Auth password protect the site first though if this is a public production server, just in case the error spits out any confidential information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just cracked my head with this problem.

If none of the above mentioned solution work, (debug, emptying cache..etc), try this one.

Open up your controller, remove any unwanted empty line especially at the top of the file anywhere around you `<?php` tag, and make sure no useless empty line around the closing `?>` tag as well.

I hope it help.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, check your server error logs. White screens are usually one of the following:

- You didn't clear out the files in /app/tmp/cache (leave the
  directories, remove any files).
- You are running out of memory (check the server logs)
- mod_rewrite is not enabled on the server or is not configured correctly (check you have allowOverride all set in your apache config so Cake's .htaccess files are read)

[edit]

- you haven't made your app/tmp directory writable by the web user

Comment: oops - missed where you mentioned you'd removed cache files, possibly an out of memory error then...

Comment: i put my old cake site in that directory and it worked, so there's probably a newline or extra space somewhere that php doesn't like